# Difference in how browsers parse dates

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, datetime, firefox

Can someone explain to me why if I paste the following into the consoles of both Chrome and Firefox I get different results

```
new Date("2014-12-01")
```

Output in Chrome:

```
Sun Nov 30 2014 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

Output in Firefox:

```
Date 2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Yes, you're reading that correctly. Chrome renders it as a day before.

[image: Chrome console screenshot]

Comment: Chrome output it as "Mon Dec 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)" for me. Maybe some odd time zone set somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each browser will show dates in the console like it wants.

In your case, Firefox seems to use [`Date.prototype.toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) under the hood:

```
new Date("2014-12-01").toISOString(); // "2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

And Chrome seems to use [`Date.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString). In my case, on Chrome and in my timezone, I get

```
new Date("2014-12-01");
    // Mon Dec 01 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora estándar romance)
new Date("2014-12-01").toString();
    //"Mon Dec 01 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora estándar romance)"
```

However, note that Chrome does not render it as a day before. It's just that it uses `GMT-0600`:

```
Date.parse("Sun Nov 30 2014 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)"); // 1417392000000
Date.parse("2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z");                // 1417392000000
```

Comment: You can also call new Date().getTime("2014-12-01") to convince yourself that they are actually the same underlying date regardless of how the browser displays it.

Comment: For reference, it's not just in the console that it's doing this. When use this new Date('2014-12-01') in a script to set a date for jQuery's date picker Chrome still renders it as Nov, 30th. Is this a setting in Chrome, or just a quirk of the underlying JS engine?

Comment: @CommodoreTimo Date objects are just objects. If you see "Nov, 30th", you are stringifying it in some way, probably using `Date.prototype.toString`, which is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for this description, @Oriol

Answer (score 1):

I think the Chrome's reading has to do with your locale settings as it converts the GMT entry to your time zone and makes the necessary adjustments whether subtracting, adding, or leaving it as is.